# Create a column based on multiple conditions in python

Tags: python

I want to create a new column - 'result', and in that column the value will be stored based on the condition below.
my conditions is -

1-col emp is 'salaried' or 'business' & col inc is '> 10 lakh' & col flg is 'stp' then add a column result with value 'no_issue'

2-col emp is 'salaried' or 'business' & col inc '<= 10 lakh' & col flg is 'n_stp' then put 'no_issue' in result

3-col emp is 'salaried' or 'business' & col inc '> 10 lakh' & col flg is 'n_stp' then put 'issue' in result

4-col emp is 'salaried' or 'business' & col inc '<= 10 lakh' & col flg is 'stp' then put 'issue' in result

5-col emp is 'other' & col flg is 'n_stp' then put 'no issue' in result

6-col emp is 'other' & col flg is 'stp' then put 'issue' in result

This is a very complex logic, Please help me to get the desired output

my final data with added column looks like -

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['1', 'stp', 'salaried', '> 10 lakh', 'no_issue'],
        ['2', 'stp', 'business', '> 10 lakh', 'no_issue' ],
        ['3', 'n_stp', 'salaried', '<= 10 lakh', 'no_issue']]

df= pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['s.no', 'flg', 'emp', 'inc', 'result'])
df


s.no    flg     emp          inc         result
1       stp     salaried    > 10 lakh    no_issue
2       stp     business    > 10 lakh    no_issue
3       n_stp   salaried    <= 10 lakh   no_issue
```

Comment: Please do not provide code or data within images. Please add the actual data to the question. Also, your question is missing a lot of information. What format is the data in? What format/program do you want to add an extra column? There is too much ambiguity to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: added sir, now it will be helpful, sorry for my mistakes

Comment: What's the difference between this and your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464036/create-a-new-column-and-assign-values-with-multiple-numpy-where-conditions-in

Answer (score 0):

is this data availabe in form of list of lists?
if yes, then you can use simple if-else condition for each case and append to the end of list

Comment: no, it is in excel,i will have to import it and create dataframe

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl
path= r"c:\  path of file"
work_book=openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheet=work_book.active
rows=sheet.max_row
columns=sheet.max_column
sheet.cell(1,columns+1).value="Result"
for i in range(2,rows):
  if (sheet.cell(i,1).value in ('salaried' , 'business') ) and (int(sheet.cell(i,3).value)>1000000) and (sheet.cell(i,4).value=='stp'):
       sheet.cell(i,5).value='no issue'
  elif #another  conditions here:
      #do something
  elif  # another  conditions here:
      # do something
      
work_book.save(path)
work_book.close()
```

Comment: i didnt get it your code, where should i put those conditions like in the income is <10 or >=10 ?

Comment: if income is at 3rd column, use sheet.cell(i,3)